# Generic mapped type property based on another property

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have an **ElementCategory** type that contains an array of elements. Those elements can be of different types.

Each element has several properties, more notably a `type` property of type `ElementType`, which is simply an enum of all element types available, and a `data` property which type varies based on the element's `type`.

I have a mapped type called `ElementsData` that, ideally, receives the element type and returns the type of data for that type of element in particular (which is not the behaviour this following code has):

```
enum ElementType {
    Text = 'text',
    Rating = 'rating',
    Picture = 'picture'
}

type TextData = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    boldTitle: boolean;
};

type RatingData =
    | {
        question: string;
        type: 'number';
        scale: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10;
        minLabel: string;
        maxLabel: string;
      }
    | {
        question: string;
        type: 'star' | 'emoji';
        scale: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;
        minLabel: string;
        maxLabel: string;
      };

type PictureData = {
    url: string;
};

type ElementData<Type> = Type extends ElementType.Text
    ? TextData
    : Type extends ElementType.Rating
    ? RatingData
    : Type extends ElementType.Picture
    ? PictureData
    : Record<string, never>;

type ElementsData = {
    [Type in ElementType]: ElementData<Type>;
};

interface ScriptElement {
    name: string;
    type: ElementType;
    data: ElementsData[ElementType];
}

type ElementCategory = {
    name: string;
    elements: ScriptElement[];
};

const defaultElementsData: ElementsData = {
    [ElementType.Text]: {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        boldTitle: false,
    },
    [ElementType.Rating]: {
        question: '',
        type: 'number',
        scale: 10,
        minLabel: '',
        maxLabel: '',
    },
    [ElementType.Picture]: {
        url: '',
    },
};


const ContentElementsCategory: ElementCategory = {
    name: 'Content',
    elements: [
        {
            name: 'Text',
            type: ElementType.Text,
            data: defaultElementsData[ElementType.Text],
        },
        {
            name: 'Picture',
            type: ElementType.Picture,
            data: defaultElementsData[ElementType.Picture],
        },
        {
            name: 'Rating',
            type: ElementType.Rating,
            data: defaultElementsData[ElementType.Rating],
        },
    ],
};
```

**My question is:** How can I assure that the `ElementType` that's passed on the `type` property is the same as the one passed to `ElementsData`?

Here's a [Repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=3&module=1&ts=4.7.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAogNsCoAuAVAngB2FA3gKCiKlWAA9koBeKAcmXOVoBpDiAlAQ2QEsQBzanQBO3PvxZsiABR4BjZGGE4atTPMXLa%20AL758yLDlIUAIt05CCASF7IEALigBnZMPEBufNYAmwZ3LumLwA9iBOru4CXtYARiFwPqg89sBO8QnAnCBeOl4GRlBcvALmyJZU3gA%20eN7WAI5g-qHhLm6edYbYTrTgELHAwrQx1gGcjlAATFA1AMwzUAAsCwCsCwBsCwDsCwAcCwCcCwCMAAwjEHwAMpwDcBHt0XUQnGQ3dw9R-DFEetY1NgaTVcPDCnw61lsRh6rk4QwWtEQIQAVjxhnUxhNpnMFssaisLtdbsB7m0vhdXu8SeCntZfvkujhZAolMAyhVatYlKTIh08vpGbAEEgQMh2QAeDDYAB8QilOEYoB8ziFiBQ8oAdCZkN4APwkRjs7xOeVQRUgZWqkVoIwa4riPVFMSlCxSKAmwrmy3wNWizXMzTAR0B1lG6xOdjAOQhYQ%20cW8gTMKAgYAAN0G0oZhR91uc7Ks3gA2qa%20Fb1UYALpOHMoCXyzO6fJ8BjCABmnDkOAAyoEeMEa6LasRk5wkDTvm7GdXheXsF5hz4LNPfcg8xZCwObdgK7kBdmZ6KAMLcYD8GPoAvDkCjtJkjrDkkr5xOHtBZCbws7xv6aMgVxQPx2zAOB3wPVd2WXXN8xoAhhw3MDNW1KtOVsFIJloSRIT8AI31BVoMNYSF4kSZJUicds4GcYBCJ0Qj4JXTV7QEZDAUaZo8J6TCoW6Og%20gGIZCNGORxlvM5BMuEAqVJAjnkpYlpMw2i3Xo61-Q0VkWLqblONYYclP5H8wn-Q8wgYUVN2cY8GDPYR0EglArNPc8C2sa8xzoEzRRQTDH1zJxCzqQFXJvHptS47jb03RDGEE3wlwA4AgJAiz2RU2dgC1RgK0EpTISCtzb1oEMtFiqcyz9W1iuouo4vKJxAM4YDQKfVKosq9TlGyuolOHYd8pCugmIkUroXKrcMqG2LFzqhKkuaqD1za7A7WdfgushXKuryIA) I've created to demonstrate the problem. If you hover over the data property in the element creation down below you'll see that it isn't detecting the exact data type based on the element type, as it is supposed to do.

*Note:* I tried making 'Element' generic, but that forced me to add a generic type annotation to the `elements` array as well, which didn't work as intended as I don't want to force a single element type in the array. Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: Increase your chances of a good answer by providing a repro in the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, *as plain text in the body of your post*. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. (If you want to provide a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbBy9m) that's great, but please also put the full example *in the body of the post as text*.)

Comment: @spender I've edited my question with a repro link

Comment: @jcalz I've added a link just now

Comment: Could you please re-read my comment and let me know how I could better convey the requirement that [mre] should be, at the very least, **in the question as plain text**?  The link is great, don't get me wrong. But we cannot require that people navigate away from SO to see the code... it needs to be plain text, in the question post, here.  Is there a better way I could have phrased it?

Comment: @jcalz No, you phrased that perfectly, I was the one who misread what you said, I'm sorry. I've edited the question, but in the meantime, the accepted answer already fixed my problems. I wanna thank you, nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to create a union of all possible combinations by mapping over the `ElementType` enum.

```
type ScriptElement = {
    name: string
} & {
    [K in ElementType]: {
        type: K,
        data: ElementsData[K]
    }
}[ElementType]
```

Now there will be an error if `type` does not match `data`.

```
const ContentElementsCategory: ElementCategory = {
    name: 'Content',
    elements: [
        {
            name: 'Text',
            type: ElementType.Text,
            data: defaultElementsData[ElementType.Text],
        },
        {
            name: 'Picture',
            type: ElementType.Picture,
            data: defaultElementsData[ElementType.Picture],
        },
        {
            name: 'Rating',
            type: ElementType.Rating,
            data: defaultElementsData[ElementType.Text], // Error 
        },
    ],
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=3&module=1&ts=4.7.4&ssl=97&ssc=3&pln=77&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAogNsCoAuAVAngB2FA3gKCiKlWAA9koBeKAcmXOVoBpDiAlAQ2QEsQBzanQBO3PvxZsiABR4BjZGGE4atTPMXLa%20AL758yLDlIUAIt05CCASF7IEALigBnZMPEBufNYAmwZ3LumLwA9iBOru4CXtYARiFwPqg89sBO8QnAnCBeOl4GRlBcvALmyJZU3gA%20eN7WAI5g-qHhLm6edYbYTrTgELHAwrQx1gGcjlAATFA1AMwzUAAsCwCsCwBsCwDsCwAcCwCcCwCMAAwjEHwAMpwDcBHt0XUQnGQ3dw9R-DFEetY1NgaTVcPDCnw61lsRh6rk4QwWtEQIQAVjxhnUxhNpnMFssaisLtdbsB7m0vhdXu8SeCntZfvkujhZAolMAyhVatYlKTIh08vpGbAEEgQMh2QAeDDYAB8QilOEYoB8ziFiBQ8oAdCZkN4APwkRjs7xOeVQRUgZWqkVoIwa4riPVFMSlCxSKAmwrmy3wNWizXMzTAR0B1lG6xOdjAOQhYQ%20cW8gTMKAgYAAN0G0oZhR91uc7Ks3gA2qa%20Fb1UYALpOHMoCXyzO6LPYKAAZUCPGCNdFBesIE4SBp-F0UAAZJzCwBpKClrs27BVzlQ7pQCesSE%20CzV4UoPMWScV7x6HSF2fyg8FZuzgDC3GA-Bj6ALxGT-bSZI6z5JvuQzicbaCyCzoWFa5Pk0YgK4UB%20AAZpwYBwIB26iru5Rbt%20KEcgQz4nkhc7AFqjALoCdgTLQkjrv47bBKCrRkWucQJEkKQTLBcDOMAa46GuOHfpq9oCERdSNM0NE9ORS5vr0kADEM9GYm%20Zz0ZcIBUqSdHPJSxJqeRXFujx1r%20horKCZC3Jiawz66fy%20jgZBV5hAwoqzs4N4MPewjoGh1quXeD49n2A50PZoooORX65k4hZ1ICvavj02riRJXnltgBEUPRviblBwCwfBiHoey%20kpfh2oVvRumQjFAWSSGWgZYyyV%20ratUcXUmWodluUIc5hWns1RnKGVdS6c%20z5VXFdD8RI9XQmWTWpVNGUbh1MFwd1uEYUV80lYR5VrkNeRAA)